# Cannot extract year from createdDate in SOQL query

Tags: salesforce, soql

```
SELECT House__r.Name, House__r.House_Owner__r.person__r.Email__c, (SELECT Name, Total_Balance__c, Total_Expense__c FROM Expenses__r Where Type__c='Yearly' AND AND CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate) =  CALENDAR_YEAR(System.today() )   FROM Member__c
```

Error=> Unknown parsing error.

Kindly suggest what else can I do.

Comment: Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You have two 'AND' in a row. Also, if you are using query editor, you can't use System.today().

Answer (score 0):

(on mobile, formatting will be poor, sorry)

SOQL supports only "field - operator - value_or_function” style for conditions. You try to make it "function - operator - another function", won't work.

For your particular scenario try with `WHERE Created date = THIS_YEAR`. It's a special literal, see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

More generic way would be to write what you need as a formula field, you could compare to YEAR(TODAY()). (that could be poor performance to filter by formula, often it results in full table scan, you would have to test, maybe add more filters using indexed columns...).

Or write it as `WHERE CreatedDate >= :start AND CreatedDate <= :stop`, put right bind variables for your range.